# Which restriction an app with CloudKit has if user does not turn on iCloud Drive

Tags: ios, cloudkit, icloud-drive

Which CloudKit services are not available if user not turns on iCloud Drive?

Is it any way to turn on iCloud Drive from app?

I guess downloading records from public container should work regardless iCloud Drive, writing container only if it is enabled?!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

CloudKit is linked to the iCloud account. If the user is login in into iCloud, but does not have iCloudDrive enabled, then there are no limitations to CloudKit.

If the user is not logged in into iCloud, then he can only access public data. You could set this on any recordType from the CloudKit dashboard.

There is no way to change the login from within your app. You can only login from the settings app. There is also no way to enable iCloud Drive from your app. For that you also need to go to the settings app

Comment: sorry you are wrong, I just retested it, if iCloud Drive is turned off, then 3 things will happen (1) `accountStatusWithCompletionHandler` will return `.NoAccount` (2) `NSFileManager.defaultManager().ubiquityIdentityToken` value is `nil` and (3) `publicDatabase.saveRecord` method will return with error. So iCloud Drive is a strict limitation by using CloudKit and a serious threat. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115648/default-state-of-icloud-drive-setting-for-a-newly-installed-app

Comment: the error I get is `saveRecord` is `<CKError 0x146b0c50: "Not Authenticated" (9/1002); "CloudKit access was denied by user settings"; Retry after 3.0 seconds>`

Comment: Strange. The documentation only mentions the iCloud account. Nothing about iCloudDrive: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFileManager/ubiquityIdentityToken

Comment: This was also an issue with Core Data with iCloud. I think iCloud Drive is basically what Apple is trying to get everyone to use. Most people have it activated.

Answer (score 12):

Here is where Apple implies iCloud Drive is required for CloudKit:

> Improve the user’s experience by verifying that the user is signed in to their iCloud account before saving records. If the user is not signed in, present an alert instructing the user how to enter their iCloud credentials and enable iCloud Drive. Insert your code that saves records in the else clause below.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH3-SW8